# Poems on Atticism by Samuel David Luzzatto (Shadal)

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rabbis, song-poetry, shadal

Can anyone find poems on Atticism for me by Samuel David Luzzatto (Shadal)?

Comment: This also appears to be off topic. Looking at the definition for Atticism from Wikipedia, this is about a linguistic form of Greek used in Greek poetry.

Answer (score 5):

They're probably in his book of poetry, "Kinor Na'im."  Link: http://www.archive.org/details/kinornaimkolelsh02luzz